# Sequentially write protobuf messages to a file in go

Tags: go, serialization, protocol-buffers, gob

I have a huge number of similar object (about hundreds of gigabytes) and I need to serialize it and write to a file sequentially and after that read it in the same order. How to do it in protobuf (gogo proto) in golang? Gob has a encoder which can write to io.Writer but protobuf don't have something similar. May be protobuf is not best choice for this purposes? I need good performance and low memory allocations.

Comment: Gob is a no-brainer, why not to stick to it?

Comment: Gob has low performance compare to gogoproto and too many allocations.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to write multiple messages to a single file or stream, it
>   is up to you to keep track of where one message ends and the next
>   begins. The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so
>   protocol buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their
>   own. The easiest way to solve this problem is to write the size of
>   each message before you write the message itself. When you read the
>   messages back in, you read the size, then read the bytes into a
>   separate buffer, then parse from that buffer.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques)

**1. Write the Protobuf**

Marshal your protobuf into a `[]byte` and call `Write` along with the file you're wanting to write to as the `io.Writer`. This writes the length of `msg` to the `io.Writer` before writing `msg` itself.

```
func Write(w io.Writer, msg []byte) error {
    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutInt32(buf, Uint32(len(msg)))

    if _, err := w.Write(buf); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if _, err := w.Write(msg); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

**2. Read the Protobuf**

When you want to read out the protobufs on the other side, open the file and pass it in as the `io.Reader`. This extracts the size from the file, then reads that amount of bytes into the `msg` buffer and returns it.

```
func Read(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    size := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf)

    msg := make([]byte, size)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(r, msg); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return msg, err
}
```

---

The `*os.File` type in Go satisfies both the `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interfaces, so you shouldn't run into any issues.

Credits to @Brits for pointing this out.

Good luck!

Comment: Writing data to an open file is done by `File.Write()`. `ioutil.WriteFile()` takes the file name not an open file, and it opens it and truncates it (it doesn't append to it).

Comment: As I understard this technique just append bytes to file and it can't be readed back as separate messages.

Comment: Write the length before each piece of encoded data  (i.e. 4 bytes for the length followed by the protobuf encoded message). This is the approach recommended in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques

Comment: Ah, Sorry, I mis-read the question. I'll update my answer. :)